# Error using eval() to name data.table column in r

Tags: r, data.table

My goal is to name a new column of a data table, based on the value of another variable. Normally, this would be straightforward, but with data tables any column name input is taken as a string, rather than a variable (i think?)

To do this, I thought I would make use of the eval function. My code:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(x = c(1,1,2,2,3), y = 6:10, z = 11:15)

sumtitle <- "Sum"

Output <- DT[ , j = list(eval(sumtitle) = sum(y)), by = x]
```

but this returns

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "Output <- DT[ , j = list(eval(sumtitle) ="
```

This is strange to me because

```
> eval(sumtitle)
[1] "Sum"
```

and

```
Output <- DT[ , j = list("Sum" = sum(y)), by = x]
```

works as expected.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is not `data.table`.  You are trying to specify an argument name as an expression, which isn't legal directly:

```
sumtitle <- "Sum"
y <- 1:10
list(eval(sumtitle) = sum(y))
# Error: unexpected '=' in "list(eval(sumtitle) ="
```

Produces the same error.  Try instead:

```
DT[ , j = setNames(list(sum(y)), sumtitle), by = x]

   x Sum
1: 1  13
2: 2  17
3: 3  10
```